# php create month dropdown based on value from database

Tags: php

I have a month dropdown, `#frm`.

The dropdown is being filled by the below code...

```
<?php
  $from_months = array(0 => 'January', 1 => 'February', 2 => 'March', 3 => 'April', 4 => 'May', 5 => 'June', 6 => 'July', 7 => 'August', 8 => 'September', 9 => 'October', 10 => 'November', 11 => 'December');
  $transposed = array_slice($from_months, date('n'), 12, true) + array_slice($from_months, 0, date('n'), true);
  $last8 = array_reverse(array_slice($transposed, -8, 12, true), true);
?>
<select class="span4" name="frm" id="frm" required>
<?php
    foreach ($from_months as $num => $name) {
        printf('<option value="%u">%s</option>', $num, $name);
    }
?>
```

Now I want to fill the dropdown (`#frm`) based on the value from database table. Like... if database table value is 4, then the dorpdown (`#frm`) will show from `4 => 'May', 5 => 'June',......` onwards.

**What should I do ?**

Answer (score 0):

Well, you just need to condition your loop.

```
$value_from_database = 4;

foreach ($from_months as $num => $name)
    if ($num >= $value_from_database)
        printf('<option value="%u">%s</option>', $num, $name);
```

Answer (score -1):

Using the logic you had for the transposed array it would be fairly simple to do this

```
<?php
$db_val=6;   // the value you get from your database

$from_months = array(0 => 'January', 1 => 'February', 2 => 'March', 3 => 'April', 4 => 'May', 5 => 'June', 6 => 'July', 7 => 'August', 8 => 'September', 9 => 'October', 10 => 'November', 11 => 'December');
$transposed = array_slice($from_months, $db_val, 12, true);
?>
<select class="span4" name="frm" id="frm" required>
<?php
foreach ($transposed as $num => $name) {
    printf('<option value="%u">%s</option>', $num, $name);
}
```

RESULT

```
<select class="span4" name="frm" id="frm" required>
<option value="6">July</option>
<option value="7">August</option>
<option value="8">September</option>
<option value="9">October</option>
<option value="10">November</option>
<option value="11">December</option>
```